# Why Jhipster takes more than 2GB Memory during build time?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, jhipster-registry

**I am using Jhipster (Version 4.13.1) with angular 4 and gradle, when I build for production my application using 'gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage' command it takes more then 2GB memory to build. My Application is very small but then it takes much memory to build. Why this happend ??**

Following script is execute when I run 'gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage' command to build and generate WAR file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "yarn run lint -- --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf build/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf build//www/app/{src,build/}",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "serve": "yarn run start",
    "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
    "test": "yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn test -- --watch",
    "webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base",
    "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=1024 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "postinstall": "node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js"
  }
```

I have also tried after change value in `node --max_old_space_size=4096`  and `node --max_old_space_size=1024` parameters  but still it takes much much memory

I noticed that it takes more the 2GB memory during Angular Build .

I have only 2GB memory in my Serves machine and I am trying to build but its failed

when my script reaches  on `"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=1024 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` this line its hang and stop responding.

*Please help me how to solve this issue and Why it takes much memory during build?*

Comment: This is what frontend tools (webpack, angular AOT compiler, etc ...) require during build, not JHipster's fault. Beside adding more memory to your server, I can only suggest to build on your PC and not on a small server.

Comment: Why webpack requires much memory to build Angular code in Jhipster ??

We also build very huge  Angular code for another project, that time it doesn't take much memory

Comment: Then compare the webpack configuration between your 2 projects, maybe your other project does not optimise bundle with AOT.